# Performance tuning of a query

Tags: sql, join

Can you help me in  tuning the below query.. Based on our requirement , we framed the below query.. But because of using more joins and millions of records  in database, this query is taking more than 9 hours to execute.. Can you suggest me an alternative way of writing this query so that it can be executed faster.

```
update CS cs1 set ACC2 =
(select concat(concat(concat(concat(concat(concat(concat(concat(concat (concat(concat(
'POA_',pol.plan),'-_-'),po.plan),'-_-'),po.plan),'-_-'), nvl      (ag.ACCUMGCRTYPE,'NA')),'-_-'), nvl(al.GROUPTYPE,'NA')),'-_-'),ac.ACCUMULATOR)   as name from 
accumulator ac
join accum_li al on (ac.AL_PK = al.pk)
join accum_gr ag on (al.AG_PK = ag.pk) join PLAN_OPT po on (ag.PO_PK = po.pk) 
join PLAN_OPTION pog on (po.POL_PK = pog.pk) join PLAN_OPTION pol on (pog.PR_O_ID = pol.pk) join plan p on ( pol.PLAN_PK = p.pk)
where cs1.ACCUM2_PK = ac.pk);
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: try add index add column use join and where, instead nvl use case when

Comment: Share with us the execution plan

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (That code is product specific.)

Comment: We are using RDBMS.. TWe ran this query using Toad